# How to mock a static method written in Java with bounded type parameters in a unit test written in Kotlin using MockK?

Tags: java, kotlin, unit-testing, mockk

I'm trying to write some unit tests in Kotlin where I need to mock a static method from a Java class (let's call it A). The tricky part is that this method has [bounded type parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html). Here's the method signature (C is a class, I is an interface):

```java
public class A {
    @NonNull
    public static <T extends C & I> A doSomething(T thing) {}
}
```

In my Kotlin test class, I'm attempting to use the MockK library to mock this static method. I want to capture the thing parameter passed to the `doSomething` method in a slot, but I'm not sure how I can do this/if this is even possible due to the bounded type parameters.

Here's the essence of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Test {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        mockkStatic(A::class)
        val thingSlot = slot<T extends C & I>()
        every { A.doSomething(capture(thingSlot)) } answers { ... }
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Kotlin using MockK? If not, what alternatives or workarounds could I consider?

The only way I could get something like this to work so far is by defining an explicit type that extends C and I, but I want this to be able to work for any type matching the generic constraint.